# Why isn't this absolute positioned div vertically centering?

Tags: html, css

I need multi-line text to be centered vertically within a parent. I need the child to be `position: absolute;` because it will have other items in there behind it. I cannot figure out how to make the child (a div containing text) vertically centered. (I also tried doing it with `display: table-cell` but couldn't get that working either)

https://jsfiddle.net/t7q1ffm2/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">This has some text in it that's long</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Short text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .box
    {
      position: relative;
      top: 0em;
      left: 0em;
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
      -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -moz-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-grow: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
      margin-right: .625em;
      margin-bottom: .5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: table;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .box .text
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      margin: auto;
      width:100%;
      height: 50%;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 1.125em;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: Because you set the height of .text to 50%.

Comment: `top: 0` so.... that's not centered.

Comment: `position:absolute` is not allowed for a flexbox child anyway. Why the hell would you 'need' it to be absolutely positioned to give it a z-index? That also works fine with relative positioning.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes With relative, I'd need to set the item underneath it to have a negative margin-top to keep it underneath. Otherwise it's pushed down. But I don't know the height of the text (could be multiple lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use position **relative/absolute**, you have to add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` on absolute element for center align.

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-right: .625em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.box .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">This has some text in it that's long</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Short text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

CSS attribute table-cell does work:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">This has some text in it that's long</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="text">Short text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: table;
}

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

However, you need to wrap that inside another box.

This fiddle illustrates your exact use case: https://jsfiddle.net/stgermaniac/qdc84bxo/

Answer (score 1):

Using `flexbox` is your best bet. [Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/xhrvutfw/2/), and here is the CSS I used (I cut out some unnecessary CSS):

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: .625em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

.box .text {
    margin: auto;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.125em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```